# Google map search using KML

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

i am using google map kml field (direct iframe code from gmap) 
for showing different locations/shops on map:
[Google map @my site](http://www.chandanbora.com/gmap.php),

i need to add a search box from where user can search nearest shops to his/her location...

can any body help me in this out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that the API does not provide support for searching your provided KML: 
[google maps API geocode finds nearby KML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718451/google-maps-api-geocode-finds-nearby-kml)

Google provides a service called placesService ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places ) which lets you make requests to their database of content and return results in the form of KML near a location within some bounded area - but to my knowledge you cannot specify the source to search. (You could try testing the placesService, with a KML layer set on your map and see if it includes your data).

Assuming you are generating your KML from a database, can you could regenerate it appropriately filtered or styled based on the user's search terms. This seems the most likely solution without additional details.

Answer (score -1):

I have done google map search with python. But this one searches hospitals

You need to get google place api and place in code and reconfigure for search,
it will print out name, location address, and website

https://github.com/rockcastle/GoogleMap-Scrapping